# Using Kajiki & Jinja together in Turbogears doesn't work

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2, turbogears2

I've configured Jinja ( base_config.renderers.append('jinja') ) and used in a controller as follows

```
@expose('jinja:a.b.c.templates.y')
def action(self):
```

I've two master layouts "abc.xhtml" and "abc.jinja"
Now Kajiki being the default renderer, takes "abc.jinja"

If I run Jinja template first, Kajiki template does not work and vice versa.

I've tried to expose by providing kajiki as the rendering engine and it too didn't work

```
@expose('kajiki:a.b.c.templates.z')
def action(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by renaming the kajiki template master "abc.xhtml" to "xyz.xhtml"